# If condition in Angular material table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using Angular material table and I want to hide a column in table on the basis of if-condition. If the condition is true the column shows on the page otherwise it hides.

this is my html code.

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="delete">   
  <th class="th" mat-header-cell  *matHeaderCellDef> Delete </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" ><span><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" (click)="check(element._id)"  style="cursor: pointer;"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dModal"></i></span> 
     </td>  
  </ng-container>
```

this is my ts code

```
 displayedColumns: string[] = ['assessment','status','action','issue','created','delete'];
```

I tried but failed can anyone help me?

Comment: Where is the condition? You could just remove and add the column in  `displayedColumns` array as per the condition.

Comment: sir i want if my flag is true the delete column appears if my flag is false delete column hides/disappear

Comment: Again, add/remove the `delete` string from the `displayedColumns` array. Eg. if condition **true**: make sure `delete` is available in the array. If not add it. If condition **false**: remove `delete` from `displayedColumns` array.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64367852/6513921) is similar to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide the column based on the if and else condition you should build the displayedColumns array dynamically.

For example.

You want to hide the delete column, the displayedColumns  array value like

```
this.displayedColumns = ['assessment','status','action','issue','created'];
```

Answer (score 1):

The @Murugan answer is nice if you have few fields. But if you have a lot os columns, could be better to use other way. In my case, I have a lot of column, like:

```
columns = [{columnDef: '1',...}, ... columnDef: '50',...]
displayedColumns = this.columns.map(c => c.columnDef);
```

and depends on the situation, I need remove column 30, 31, 43. Then I have other `displayedColumnsToRemove = ['30','31','43',]`

in my conditional I remove it

```
if (conditional) {
  this.displayedColumns = _.xor(this.displayedColumns,this.displayedColumnsToRemove);
      }
```

I'm using [loadsh library (_.xor)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash), but if you can't, looking for other way to remove this elements.